# Changing the cursor color of an edittext in an alertdialog

Tags: android, android-layout

My problem is, that I have an alertdialog with a black cursor in the edittext field. I want to change this color to white. You can easily set the color of the edittext to white by:

```
    edittext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

The problem is, that the cursor color is still black. So I did some research and found some articles about changing the cursor color in the xml file by adding this code:

```
   android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/white_cursor"
```

the white_cursor.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="1dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"  />
    </shape>
```

So I generated the edittext in the xml file and do the findById()-function:

```
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eText);
```

But when the show()-method is being called, the application crashes. Did anyone know how I could change the cursor color in my code or how to implement that without errors? thx

Edit 1 alertdialog code:

```
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eText);
    InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
    filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20);
    input.setFilters(filters);
    input.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    alertbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
    alertbuilder.setTitle("Enter the levelname!");
    alertbuilder.setMessage("To change the levelname after it has been created, tap and hold the icon of the level.");

    alertbuilder.setView(input);

    alertbuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int whichButton) {
    Editable value = (Editable) input.getText();
      // Do stuff
        dialog.dismiss();

      }

    });

    alertbuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          dialog.dismiss();
      }
    });
    alertadd=alertbuilder.create();
    alertadd.show(); //crash here
```

edit2 logcat:

```
04-22 20:00:34.217: D/OpenGLRenderer(2475): Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-22 20:00:37.216: D/Input(2475): VelocityTracker: int datax = 15
04-22 20:00:37.216: D/Input(2475): VelocityTracker: int m_velocity_magnify_x = 1.500000
04-22 20:00:37.216: D/Input(2475): VelocityTracker: int datay = 20
04-22 20:00:37.216: D/Input(2475): VelocityTracker: int m_velocity_magnify_y = 2.000000
```

I get not an error message in my logcat. I actually get a Class File Editor - Source not found - Error

Comment: Post your alert dialog code...

Comment: Post the LogCat error.

Comment: is your edittext is part of your layout..? i.e is it part of layout set by setContentView for the current Activity?

Comment: yes, it's in my RelativeLayout, that is created in the setContentView-method... don't know how I could implement this without beeing in a layout.

Comment: Should I put in another xml layout, that isnt showed? I think this might also get an error.

Comment: Yea, I have solved the problem. You have to remove the edittext from the relativelayout (relativelayout.removeView(input);)! Thx to Pragnani for the hint! Everything is working fine now... I'm just woundering, why there is no way to change the cursor color programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eText);
```

You can't set that `EditText` as Dialog content if it part of your Activity/Fragment layout.

I suggest you to create a file `dialog_content.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText 
    style="@style/yourEditTextStyle"
    android:id="@+id/myEditTextId"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

And creating the `EditText` in this way:

```
input = (EditText) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_content, null);
```

Comment: Yea, this sounds well. I actually solved my problem by removing the edittext from the relativelayout, but this solution is a more solid way...I'm just still wondering, why there is no way to change the cursor color programmatically.